# Why the path mapping is not redirecting to the page?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a 3 simple classes:

dis - DispatcherServlet

```
public class dis extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] {rpt.class};
}

protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[0];
}

protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] {"/"};
}
}
```

rpt - Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.t")
public class rpt implements WebMvcConfigurer {
}
```

control -Controller

```
@RestController
public class control {
    @GetMapping({"", "/"})
    public String fdfsd() {
        return "rest test";
    }
}
```

But when I start the server spring returns not rest test text, but 404 error page. I looked various project on github and them structure looked the same, so I have no clue what is wrong. Do I must add something?

My dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

It turned out that in the depths of my compiler default application context path was set to "/unnamed" insted of "/". So awkward ._.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/annotated/student/{studentId}")
```

This is the pattern used on spring.io, try it on your case

Comment: Loke `@GetMapping(value = "{adas})`? Not worked. Maybe something wrong with dispather?

Comment: @GetMapping(value = "/")
public String fdfsd() {
        return "rest test";
    }

Comment: 1) @ComponentScan("com.t") is this right?
2) if u can, pls post the github link, for i can try to find differences

Comment: Anyway thank you for your help in solving this problem :)